# How to run EMR Cluster Steps concurrently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr

Hi I have an EMR cluster.  Whenever I submit "steps" to it, it runs them sequentially.  Is there any way to run "steps" concurrently?

Or is the appropriate use case to spin up multiple clusters at the same time if you want concurrency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each step is processed concurrently across the cluster.  So really if you have work that can be done concurrently, you might consider having it all in the same step (each step can have 1 or more Hadoop jobs).

Typically you might use steps when you want to make sure that ALL processing that needs to be done for the following step is completed before moving to the next step. A good example of this might be when you are dealing with encrypted data, where to might have one step to decrypt the data, one step to process the data, and an additional step to re-encrypt the data before persistence.

Comment: Ok.  Let's say you want to run two different jobs on decrypting/encrypting different data sources.  In that case, you'd want to do the two different jobs in parallel.  Would you at that point create two EMR clusters?

Comment: @SeanBollin I would say that depends on a number of factors.  Are the data related such that data from one "job" is needed by the other?  (if yes, you need same cluster, unless you want to persist data in between).  Which makes sense from an economical standpoint? The different jobs may need different cluster sizes to complete work in an acceptable time frame. Are you better off running a smaller job on an oversized cluster in shorter time or on a right-sized cluster an an acceptable time.  Do you have a dedicated "always on" cluster (i.e. using reserved instances)? You have to find what works

Answer (score 0):

EMR supports running steps in parallel as of Nov. 2019: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-emr-now-allows-you-to-run-multiple-steps-in-parallel-cancel-running-steps-and-integrate-with-aws-step-functions/.  According to this document, you must be using EMR version 5.28.0 or higher.